# utm_content info is missing in firebase_campaign event

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, firebase-dynamic-links

I have made a firebase dynamic link for app install referrer and passing it to playstore for new install. I am receiving source, medium and campaign params but content and term is missing.

Comment: Can share example of your dynamic link where issue happens?